# Set output type based on input type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an array of strings and returns an array of objects. Those objects need to be typed based on the input.

Each input has its own type.

This is the code I'm using in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to test it

```
interface SerializedStrings extends Array<string> { }
interface SerializedSpawns extends SerializedStrings { }
interface SerializedContainers extends SerializedStrings { }

interface Structure extends String { }
interface StructureSpawn extends Structure { }
interface StructureContainer extends Structure { }

let spawnIDs = <SerializedSpawns>[
    "abcdef",
    "ghijkl"
]

let containerIDs = <SerializedContainers>[
    "abcdef",
    "ghijkl"
]

function inflate(input: SerializedContainers): StructureContainer[]
function inflate(input: SerializedSpawns): StructureSpawn[]
function inflate(input: SerializedStrings):  Structure[]{
    let output = input.map(function (value) {
        return "spawn-" + value
    })

    return output
}

let spawns = inflate(spawnIDs)

let containers = inflate(containerIDs)
```

`spawns` should have the type `StructureSpawn[]` and containers should have the type `StructureContainer[]` but they both had the type `StructureContainer[]` which is just the first in the list.

How do I get the output type to depend on the input type?

Comment: to me it looks like you are always returning string..

Comment: This is a simplified example. so yes the output of this function is always a string but its not in my actual use.

Comment: Currently there's no structural difference between `SerializedSpawns` and `SerializedContainers`. Just add any unique property to one of them and compiler will be able to infer type properly

Comment: @Arcath then please add an example that reflects that, it is important to the answer you would get. :)

Comment: @AlekseyL.Thanks! adding `_type: 'Container'` / `_type: 'Spawn'` respectively fixed it!